# HTML table that uses rowspan and colspan gets overlapped by the next element

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am designing a very simple table that contains a data element's properties. This element will be used to represent each element of a AJAX response in a kind of list.

The table is using "rowspan" and "colspan" to enlarge some cells. The problem, is that when I add an element below, this element overlaps the table, I don't know why. The HTML is valid, and the rowspan attributes indicate the exact amount of rows to merge.

I have deployed an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/vtortola/KzjKg/9/

As you can see, the green block overlaps the table, and that is the thing I want to avoid.

Any idea why is this happening?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've attributed `max-height:50px;` to the div which contains the table. Remove this CSS declaration, and the table won't be overlapped any more.

Comment: damn... Is there a way to force the maximun height of a table? Thanks.

Comment: You could add `overflow:auto` to the container div, so that the table won't go "outside the box". This adds scrollbars to the div, when necessary.

Comment: @vtortola
The scrollbars will only appear when it's necessary, to comply with the defined `max-height`. I've proposed two solutions: Either remove `max-height` from the div (so that the table gets as much space as needed), or add `overflow:auto` to the div, so that the div gets scrollbars when necessary.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, but neither of both solutions will constrain the table to a specific height. I guess that is not possible.

Comment: No. You're currently restricting the containers height by using `max-height`. Remove this declaration, and the desired result will be achieved.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem:

1) You maybe remove the max-height where your table is more than 50px.

```
div.mobileRow{
width:100%;
font-family:Arial;
margin:5px;}
```

Comment: can't add comment above, but overflow:auto will cut the table. and the scrollbars might not appear :(